# Spring Batch multiple different sources reading pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am trying to found the best design pattern to read multiple **different** sources, manipulate them and write into a file.

So I have an LDAP server with a branch containing *Users* and another branch containing *Services*. An User can have multiples services (represented with multi valued field on User) and I need services details on each User. I also need to log how many Users and Services have been found in the LDAP. First question : any Ldap reader available from spring batch infrastructure ?

I also have a database containing user extras informations in multiples tables (ex: users extras, options, ...). LDAP users can have DB extra informations or not (associated by user id).

I also need to log how many users extras informations have been found in database and log orphan informations (that is not related with a ldap user).

Finally, I need to merge this differents datas into one file with a header (merge LDAP and DB informations).

What is the **best pattern** to perform that ? (*reader/processor/writer* pattern seems to be unappropriate to summarize results like [Driving query based itemReaders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders)...)

Comment: Not sure what the link has to do with your problem. Read the users from LDAP, obtain the services and additional db information in a (or multiple chained) `ItemProcessor`s, create an `ItemWriter` that writes what you want,  or first create a final `ItemProcessor` that transforms the data into what you want and writes that. You might be able to read everything for a user in one go from LDAP so that additional processor might not be needed.

Comment: Ok but an `ItemProcessor` create and return only one item by process. I cannot fetch all my users datas into a processor ?

Comment: You can return whatever you like... I don't really get your comment, you can do whatever you like and return in/from an `ItemProcessor`.

Comment: The `ItemWriter` process a List of `ItemProcessor` return type. So I can't (semantically) return only one object that contains a list of complete users (list of one object that is a list)...

Comment: Sure you can, then it would proces a list of lists... Also why would you return multiple results? The only thing you are doing is enriching the passed in User imho. So User in and User out with added services and another for the database stuff.

Comment: Ok that can works but *I am trying to found the best design pattern*

Comment: That is highly opinionated and there is no general rule of thumb I would say.